# A question about an equivalent definition of the Schwartz distribution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hello,

Does anyone know a reference or proof of the "if" part of the following statement?

$$
\mu\in \mathcal{S}'(R)\quad\text{if and only if}\quad \mu*\alpha\in\mathcal{S}(R),\forall \alpha\in C_c^\infty(R),
$$

where $\mathcal{S}'(R)$ is the space of Schwartz distributions, and $\mathcal{S}(R)$ is the space of smooth function with rapid decrease. I noticed that in [Schwartz's book (1966)](http://books.google.com/books?id=ziDvAAAAMAAJ&q=th%25C3%25A9orie+des+distributions&dq=th%25C3%25A9orie+des+distributions&hl=en&ei=aBEvTs3jLMPMsgbZzfQJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA) there is a proof. I am not good at french. I am wondering whether anyone knows any other references about this matter? It may use the [Banach–Steinhaus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Steinhaus_theorem) in certain way.

By the way, whether can we improve the above results by asking $\alpha\in\mathcal{S}(R)$?

Thank you very much for any hints. :-)

Anand

Comment: You can choose $\alpha$ Schwartz distribution. Just apply the Fourier transform, which makes the convolution into a product. Since $C^\infty_c( \mathhb{R})$ is dense in $S(\mathbb{R})$, these statement should be equivalent.

Comment: About the first statement after Fourier transforming, you get a well defined functional $\widehat{\mu}: \widehat{ C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and proving continuity you'd be done.

Comment: @pm, thank you. I see. How about the "if" part of the original statement?


Comment: That is a suggestion for the "if" part, meaning that if it's well defined, then continuity comes for free... I mean this is basically the content of the statement, isn't?

Comment: Thanks pm. As for the if part, your hint is not directly obvious for me. I will have a careful consideration. :-)
